# API call IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding-xq - Python or Postman

Tags: python-3.x, api, nlp, ibm-watson

I'm struggling to connect to the IBM Watson API for Natural Language Understanding.

I've added it to the Resource list in my IAM account. I've got to the page with an example POST request to connect to the API, and I can't seem to authenticate. I've blanked out the API key from this request but in the pages the key is supplied so I'm struggling to see why it's not working

```
curl -X POST -u "#######" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{  "text": "I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the 
American dream. I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up and 
live out the true meaning of its creed: \"We hold these truths to be 
self-evident, that all men are created equal.\"",  "features": {    
"sentiment": {},    "keywords": {}  }}' \
"https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/natural-language- 
understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-19"
```

I've tried pasting this into Postman but I just get a 401 Unauthorized response, which makes me think it's something in the account pages of the IAM, but they've chnage the interface and not update the documentation, and I'm going round in circles because the instructions don't match the menus.

Any pointers would be appreciated. I intend to query through Python, so I'm hoping once I can get past the authentication issue it's as simple as copying the Python code out of Postman

Comment: Have you tried the python SDK? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

Comment: No, getting the Python working was step 2 I'm stuck on step 1 which is testing the API  authentication using Postman. I tend to check my authentication is working first before I work on the Python code, then I can isolate which element is failing. I'll give it ago though because your link seems to suggest the SDK seems to look after handling the token ... so thanks, I'll let you know ...

Comment: I had a go but got "raise WatsonApiException(response.status_code, message=error_message, httpResponse=response)
watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error: Provided API key could not be found, Code: 400"

Comment: Got it working. Many thanks. See my answer below about deleting and recreating the API key

Answer (score 1):

Your -u credentials should be:

```
-u "apikey:#######"
```

As per the API documentation - 
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#authentication

Comment: Yes I was being over zealous with me #### out the apikey, the IBM website includes -u "apikey:#######" in the curl code iexample, and that's what  I was trying to use. Postman doesn't cope with  the -u element of the code when I paste it directly from the IBM site. The authorization in Postman is "Inherit auth from parent" and I'm unsure how to generate the -u part in the Postmaninterface. If anyone has suggestions that would at least mean I can get a valid response and not an authorization error. Currently I can't completely rule out whether it's my IAM account setup at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the API credentials were not being recognised. I must have done something wrong in the initial IAM setup, which meant that when I deleted the credentials, re-created them and then copied the new key ... everything immediately started working. Complete mystery as to why but hopefully this helps someone. Here are the instructions I followed

[https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutoria](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutorial)l

I used the SDK as suggested by Simon O'Doherty

It might also be related to me having gone into the "Manage" >> "Account" and deleted any Access Groups and Service IDs I'd attempted to create by following the "Getting Started with IAM" instructions from here, which I suspect might have been what confused me

[IAM getting started (not required)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iam/quickstart.html#getstarted)